# (emu8086) multiplying 3x3 matrix with array

Tags: x86, assembly

if anyone knows assembler language i'd really need some help debugging my program. I have a 3x3 matrix and a 3 element vector that i read from the console, and i need to multiply them and display the resulting array.

This is my code so far:

```
name "2x2_matrix"
include "emu8086.inc"
org 100h ; directive make tiny com file.


.model small
.stack 100h
.data

size    dw      3  
A       db      ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?     
B       db      ?,?,?
C       db      ?,?,?

message_a db 10,13,"type the elements of matrix A:$"
message_b db 10,13,"type the elements of array B:$"
rez db 10,13,"the result is:$"     

.code 
start: 
mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax

mov bx, 0  ; 

 read_a: 
;compare with sizexsize
mov ax, size
mul size
cmp bx, ax
je reset_counter

;display message
mov dx, offset message_a
mov ah, 09h
int 21h

;read element
mov ah, 01h
int 21h
sub al, 30h
mov A[bx], al

inc bx
jmp read_a

reset_counter:
mov bx, 0        
jmp read_b    

read_b:  
;compare with size
mov ax, size
cmp bx, ax
je calcul

;display message
mov dx, offset message_b
mov ah, 09h
int 21h

;read element
mov ah, 01h
int 21h
sub al, 30h
mov B[bx], al

inc bx
jmp read_b

calcul:
mov bx,0 
mov cx,0  

for_i:       
    mov ax, size
    cmp bx, ax
    je print 

    mov al,b.size
    mul bx

    mov al, A[bx+1]
    mov bh, B[bx+1]
    mul bh
    add C[bx], ah

    mov al, b.A[bx+2]
    mov bl, b.B[bx+2]
    mul al
    add C[bx], ah

    mov al, b.A[bx+3]
    mov bl, b.B[bx+3]
    mul al
    add C[bx], ah

    inc bx
    jmp for_i               

print:

mov dx, offset rez
mov ah,09h
int 21h

mov     ax,size
mul     size
mov     cx,ax
mov     ax,0
mov     bx,0

print_c:

    cmp     bx,cx
    je      finish

    mov     al, C[bx]
    CALL    PRINT_NUM

    inc     bx
    jmp     print_c

DEFINE_PRINT_NUM
DEFINE_PRINT_NUM_UNS

finish:
ret

end start

end
```

It seems to loop and not display anything after i insert the elements, and i'm not sure how to debug it. If anyone is familiar with assembler-type coding and can help me fix my code i'd greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

By reading the provided code I found some strange lines:

```
mov bh, B[bx+1]
mul bh
```

Here you assign the register `bh` (and ultimately `bx` too) a new value to be multiplied to `ah`. But you also use `bx` as the index of your result array. It seems to me as if you change your array index while calculating the necessary information.

The same goes for the following lines

```
mov al, b.A[bx+2]
mov bl, b.B[bx+2]
mul al
add C[bx], ah

mov al, b.A[bx+3]
mov bl, b.B[bx+3]
mul al
add C[bx], ah
```

But here you should be aware that you multiply `al` with `al` which I assume is not the desired operation.

As a solution you could rename every occurence of `bh` or `bl` to `dh/dl` or `ch/cl` and change the factor in the multiplication accordingly. Then the index remains the same and the loop will work.